# How to create an ordered rank/group based on consecutive values?

Tags: sql, group-by, google-bigquery

I have the following table schema:

| id | text | persons | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | hi | p1 | 2022-08-26 21:03:16.697000 |
| 001 | how are you doing? | p1 | 2022-08-26 21:03:17.528000 |
| 001 | i'm doing fine | p2 | 2022-08-26 21:03:18.234000 |
| 001 | hey guys! | p3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:25.349000 |
| 001 | sorry | p3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:25.723000 |
| 001 | i'm late | p3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:26.129000 |
| 002 | good morning bois | p1 | 2023-01-13 18:37:16.697000 |
| 002 | time for some ranked games eh? | p1 | 2023-01-13 18:37:17.528000 |
| 002 | i've been waiting | p2 | 2023-01-13 18:37:18.234000 |
| 002 | let's go | p2 | 2023-01-13 18:37:18.234000 |
| 002 | hey guys! | p3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:25.349000 |
| 002 | sorry | p3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:25.723000 |
| 002 | i'm late | p3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:26.129000 |

**Desired Output:**

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | p1: hi how are you doing? p2: i'm doing fine p3: hey guys! sorry i'm late |
| 002 | p1: good morning bois time for some ranked games eh? p2: i've been waiting let's go! p3: hey guys! sorry i'm late |

What is a good, efficient way to get the **desired output** using SQL?
OR..
How do I create an intermediate table with column "C" below?

I've been able to achieve this using Python + Pandas , but I'd like to do this operation using SQL. So this is what I've done using Python + Pandas:

First I create an **intermediate table** with column 'C' that groups each consecutive text by persons as a unique 'C' group. Then I do a group by the id, text and persons columns and aggregate on the text to achieve the desired results above.

**Intermediate Table**:

| id | text | persons | C | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | hi | p1 | 1 | 2022-08-26 21:03:16.697000 |
| 001 | how are you doing? | p1 | 1 | 2022-08-26 21:03:17.528000 |
| 001 | im doing fine | p2 | 2 | 2022-08-26 21:03:18.234000 |
| 001 | hey guys! | p3 | 3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:25.349000 |
| 001 | sorry | p3 | 3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:25.723000 |
| 001 | i'm late | p3 | 3 | 2022-08-26 21:03:26.129000 |
| 002 | good morning bois | p1 | 1 | 2023-01-13 18:37:16.697000 |
| 002 | time for some ranked games eh? | p1 | 1 | 2023-01-13 18:37:17.528000 |
| 002 | i've been waiting | p2 | 2 | 2023-01-13 18:37:18.234000 |
| 002 | let's go | p2 | 2 | 2023-01-13 18:37:18.234000 |
| 002 | hey guys! | p3 | 3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:25.349000 |
| 002 | sorry | p3 | 3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:25.723000 |
| 002 | i'm late | p3 | 3 | 2023-01-13 18:37:26.129000 |

Here's the command I used in Python + Pandas to get the desired output:

```
df['C'] = (df.persons.ne(df.persons.shift())).astype(int).cumsum()
df.groupby(['C','persons','id'], as_index=False)['text'].agg(' '.join)
```

I attempted this using SQL as well, but couldn't get the C column to work:

```
SELECT text, 
       persons, 
       row_number() over (partition by id, persons order by timestamp) as C
FROM table
ORDER BY timestamp
```

Comment: The sql available tools depend on the DBMS you're currently using. Which one would be appropriate for you?

Comment: Your sql looks ok, other than if you actually have a column named "timestamp".  What error are you getting?

Comment: just to clarify:

@lemon, im using Google BigQuery.

Comment: @Andrew The issue I'm facing is that I'm unable to get the intermediate table with column "C" using SQL and I can only achieve that using pandas + python. The SQL query that I written is my attempt to recreate the intermediate table using SQL, but I'm not getting the same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could apply [`STRING_AGG`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg) twice:

- first to aggregate on persons, and add "p:"
- then to aggregate all your partial texts

In order to ensure the ordering of your messages, you need to carry timestamp in the aggregate operations.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT id,
           MIN(timestamp) AS timestamp,
           CONCAT(persons, ': ', STRING_AGG(text, ' ' ORDER BY timestamp), ' ') AS text,
    FROM tab
    GROUP BY id, 
             persons
)
SELECT id, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(text, ' ' ORDER BY timestamp) AS text
FROM cte
GROUP BY id
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server then you can use `string_agg()` (major dbms supports this or something like this):

Query:

```
select id,string_agg(persons+' : '+txt,' ') text from
(
select id,persons,string_agg([text],' ') txt from chat_messages
group by id,persons
)t
group by id
```

Output:

| id | text |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | p1 : hi how are you doing? p2 : i'm doing fine p3 : hey guys! sorry i'm late |
| 002 | p1 : good morning bois time for some ranked games eh? p2 : i've been waiting let's go p3 : hey guys! sorry i'm late |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/IOHYWQhQ)